# Get Email from IdentityServer 4 using ASPNetIdentity

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, claims-based-identity, identityserver4

Here is my structure.

-Asp.Net c# Application with IdentityServer 4 used to register and authenticate a user.

-Asp.Net C# Web API that serve some services that used Identity4Server to Authorize a user

-Angular 4 application with ocid-client that use the ASP.Net C# Application to authenticate the angular app.

**Question :**
Actually, when I Print the Authenticated User Claims in the Web API application, I do not see the User Email. Is there a way to see it in the claim.

**In WEB API application**

```
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var claims = User.Claims.ToList();
        //Would like to see the User Email Informations
        var AspnetUserId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == "sub").Value;

        this.ContactService.UpdateUserProfile(AspnetUserId,profile);
    }
```

**In Indentity Server Application**

```
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "tgc",
            ClientName = "Tag Twee Client Angular",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

            RequireConsent = false,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/login" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/logout" },
            AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:5002" },
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "TTAPI",
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add value in dbo.AspNetUserClaims (in ASPNetIdentity database)
the IdentityServer4 will get value from this table and set into user claims.

Comment: thanks a lot. I added the value, but it's not visible in my API of User.Claims

Comment: did you add scope & claim type in IdentityServer's  dbo.IdentityResources & dbo.IdentityClaims ??

Comment: yes I do , now I see something in the API but. I only see Scope as the Type of claims and Email as the value...

Comment: ClaimType is stored in table [IdentityClaims], like email, email_verified, (email is also as a Scope, but it includes email & email_verified two ClaimTypes), and mapping to table [AspNetUserClaims]'s ClaimType.